# Relative values from max values Maths Problem

Tags: java, math

This is more Maths related than a CS question, but I would like the answer in CS.

What I want to do is find a value relative to the max value. For instance say the value is 3. The max is 6. Therefore this value is 0.5 of the max value.

It can be implemented quite easily like this:
currentValue / max

However, say if now I have negatives.
Say the max is now -6 and the current value is -7. I would need to use the minimum value for this. So say the minimum value is -8. In this case, -7 will be 0.5 of -6.

However, how can I express finding the current value as an equation for negatives (using max and min)?

Comment: Are you concerned with whether the `max` is negative or the `currentValue` is negative?

Comment: Both max and current are negative in the second example I gave. -6 is the max. -7 is the current. -8 is the minimum. -7 is 0.5 of max in the above case on scale of 0 to 1

Comment: What is the overall goal? Do you want to map all values in a collection to the interval [0, 1], with the minimum value mapping to zero and the maximum value mapping to one? This treats the cases with and without negative numbers identically. Or would you want to smallest element of a collection of positive numbers to be greater than zero? This treats the cases distinctly, but is probably closest to question as posed.

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to assume that when `max` is positive, `min` is zero, since that's what your example suggests.

The final value you seek, given an `input` is the *proportion* of the change from `min` to `max` that the change from `min` to `input` consists of. It's actually easier in a formula:

```
Final value = (input - min) / (max - min)
```

For example:

```
min = 0
max = 6
input = 3
Final value = (3 - 0) / (6 - 0) = 3 / 6 = 0.5

min = -8
max = -6
input = -7
Final value = (-7 - -8) / (-6 - -8) = 1 / 2 = 0.5
```

Comment: Yes, this is right I guess. I would vote up, but need higher rep :)

Answer (score 0):

In effect, you want to treat the minimum value as if it were the zero on your axes. To do that, just subtract `min` from all values, giving

```
(currentValue - min) / (max - min)
```

You should check to make sure you don't divide by zero.

Comment: works for negative min value. For positive value, however, you have to take min as 0. otherwise : (min, curr/max) 2/3/6 = 0/1/4 = 0.25 instead of 0.5

Comment: @PATRY Maybe so. I was thinking of `min` more as a function parameter than necessarily as the minimum from a collection of values.

Answer (score 0):

case 1: if zero comes in between the max number and current value,you can use the distance between current value and zero over total distance between current value and max value .

case 2: if max value comes  in between  current value and zero , you can use the distance between current value and max over the total distance between zero and current value.

case 3:if current value comes in between max and zero use distance between zero and current value over distance between zero and max value.

since you need a value from o through 1,in your choice of numerator you can find and use the smaller segment.for ex- if the currentvalue and zero segment is shorter than the segment between zero and max value,use the former as numerator.